# How to make a matplotlib graph scrollable if the number of subplots is very large

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am creating a graph in which there are 11x12=132 subplots. Needless to the graph is looking cumbersome and unreadable. It would have been great if there would have been a scrollable feature in the graph so that the individual subplots could have looked a bit larger.

How can we add the scrollable feature in a graph consisting of subplots so that each of the subplots looks a bit larger?

[image]

Here is my code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_function(sampled_date, i, j, n, days, div):
    filtered_df = df.loc[(df['date'] == sampled_date) & (df['day_fraction']==j)] 
    plt.subplot(days+1, div, n)
    y, x, _ = plt.hist(filtered_df["gas_price_gwei"], bins=800)    
    plt.xlabel(j)
    plt.ylabel(sampled_date)    
    plt.text(x.max()*(0.25), y.max()*(0.75),str("{:.2f}".format(filtered_df['gas_price_gwei'].std())))
      
    
    
    
def cumulative_plot_function(a, n, days,div):
    cumulative_filtered_df = df.loc[df['day_fraction']==a] 
    plt.subplot(days+1, div, n)
    y, x, _ =plt.hist(cumulative_filtered_df["gas_price_gwei"], bins=800)    
    plt.xlabel(a)
    plt.ylabel("Across All Dates")    
    plt.text(x.max()*(0.25), y.max()*(0.75), str("{:.2f}".format(cumulative_filtered_df['gas_price_gwei'].std())))



import datetime
n=1
sampled_date = from_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
plt.subplots(days,div,figsize=(15,15))
for i in range(1, days+1):
    for j in range(1, div+1):
        plot_function(sampled_date, i, j, n, days, div)        
        n=n+1        
    datetimeobj_sampled_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(sampled_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    datetimeobj_sampled_date=datetimeobj_sampled_date+timedelta(days=1)
    sampled_date = datetimeobj_sampled_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
for a in range(1,div+1):
    cumulative_plot_function(a, n, days,div)
    n=n+1
```